# Has Brigitte Gabriel ever claimed that “all Muslims are radical Muslims”?

Tags: quotes

The blog, [love and rage media](https://loveandragemedia.org/2017/06/14/gallery-antifa-counterdemonstration-of-march-against-sharia-in-syracuse/) claims in reference to ACT! for America's leader, Brigitte Gabriel:

> The march was organized by ACT for America, one of the largest anti-Muslim groups in the US, whose leader says that “all Muslims are radical Muslims”. Many marches ended up being small rallies characterized by an overwhelming presence of counterdemonstrators. Syracuse was no exception, with numbers of antifa peaking at nearly triple those who attended ACT for America’s event.

Has Brigitte Gabriel ever claimed that “all Muslims are radical Muslims”?

I google about that and looked into her [SPLC profile](https://www.splcenter.org/hatewatch/2017/03/23/who-real-brigitte-gabriel) which doesn't have any info on that quote. Her Wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigitte_Gabriel#Viewpoints) also doesn't comment about that quote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not an exact quote.

The supposed quote emanates from her two hour interview with Jason Frankel of The Australian Jewish News, summarized in his article [The world according to
Brigitte Gabriel](https://web.archive.org/web/20070907090017/http://www.ajn.com.au/news/news.asp?pgID=3403) (6 June 2007):

> GABRIEL: That's the problem -- most people are not familiar with the tenets of the Koran.
>
> FRENKEL: Practising Muslims are radical Muslims?
>
> GABRIEL: Every practising Muslim is a radical Muslim... if he upholds the tenets of the Koran, if he goes to the Mosques, because they are being fed nothing other than the Koran.
>
> FRENKEL: Do you agree with that statement: A practising Muslim is a radical Muslim?
>
> GABRIEL: A practising Muslim who upholds the tenets of the Koran -- it's not that simple -- a practising Muslim who goes to mosque every Friday, prays five times a day, and who believes that the Koran is the word of god, and who believes that Mohammed is the perfect man and (four inaudible words) is a radical Muslim.
>
> FRENKEL: Why do you put those qualifiers on at the end?
>
> GABRIEL: They're not qualifiers because this is what a practising Muslim does…

Comment: Of course, Jewish people who obey all the laws of the Old Testament would likely be considered radical as well considering how many of the religious rules presented there require the death penalty as a punishment for violation. And I suspect you could find quite a few Christians who fit that description as well. Then again, "radical" is more of a buzzword these days than a proper descriptor considering how people seem to use it now.

Comment: @JAB leaving aside theology (which is too complicated for comments), let's look at statistics. Look at [% of Muslims who believe that apostates have to be killed according to polling data, or stoning for adultery](http://www.pewforum.org/2013/04/30/the-worlds-muslims-religion-politics-society-beliefs-about-sharia/). The #s are above 50% in many MM countries. Compare that to # of Jews who believe that any of Old Testament death punishments should be done.

Comment: The question is not about what Muslims in general actually are or believe.  It's about whether this particular person said what she is claimed to have said, not whether that statement is true or false.

Comment: She weaseled out of answering the question in a clear Yes or No manner. She did not claim it as such, she tried to imply it but in a manner which would not get her sued.

Comment: @RedSonja Could she be (successful) be sued for saying that in Australia?  In the United States she would have the freedom of speech to say that.

Comment: @DavePhD I know nothing of the Law. But saying "all Xs are Y" is tricky when there are lawyers around. She is phrasing it very carefully and I presume that is why.

Comment: @RedSonja I don't think it has to do with lawyers.  I think she really believes that some people who self-identify as Muslims, but don't take everything in the Quran literally, are non-radicals.  This talks about her threatening to kick people out of her organization for "propagating bigotry" and people in her organization are criticizing her saying “she believes Islam is a very peaceful religion and ACT is only concerned about a few radicals who have hijacked Islam” https://www.splcenter.org/hatewatch/2017/03/23/who-real-brigitte-gabriel

Comment: @DavePhD you can read it that way too.

Comment: @user5341 The difference is that the Jewish people are currently living in a developed nation, which they have acquired through war crimes and western support. Most muslims nations are not likewise developed, and naturally, radicalism goes hand in hand with human development index. So, your statistics say less about muslims, and more about the ethics of a third world country. For example, if you conducted similar statistics for certain African Christian nations, you would also see major support for barbaric rules of law. And, likewise, if you look at (the few) developed muslim nations....

Comment: ....the support for Sharia law is minor. Turkey or Azerbaijan, for example.